# Using Cloud Foundry events to audit successful deletion of orgs/spaces

Tags: events, cloud-foundry

I intend to use the [events defined in the Cloud Foundry API](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/263/#events) in order to verify that the deletion of an org or a space including all service instances has been successful. The CF events should in principle provide all necessary information. 
In order to test I created a space with a few deployed apps and service instances bound to the apps. using

```
cf curl "/v2/events"
```

I could see the related events. Now I deleted the space via

```
cf curl "/v2/spaces/<my-space-guid>?recursive=true&async=true" -X DELETE
```

Again, executing

```
cf curl "/v2/events?q=space_guid:<my-space-guid>"
```

I expected to see a number of events for the deletion of all entities in the space including the space deletion event itself. Unfortunately I did not see ANY event for the space. It looks like they were all deleted with the space. I cannot imagine that this is the intended lifecycle of such (audit) events?!?

Does anybody have any own experience with the API? Any reference to details on the defined behaviour?

Comment: This looks buggy (tested w/ CF v264).  If I delete a space with an app in it and then search with the filter `space_guid:<guid>`, I cannot find the event.  However, if I search with a filter of `organization_guid:<guid>`  where guid is the org guid that contained the space, I do see the delete space event (and delete app event).  IMO, seems like the space_guid filter is not working right.

Comment: Check out the `get events` plugin - https://github.com/ECSTeam/cf_get_events.
You can get events for a given period (max is 90 days). The plugin calls the api `/v2/events` and iterates over.